# Understanding analogy between correlation formulas in Matlab for correlation coefficient

Tags: matlab, correlation

I'm having a hard time understanding that these formulas for computing the correlation coefficient are identical (let x and y be column vectors):

1. `cov(x,y)/(std(x)*std(y))`
2. `((zscore(x)')*zscore(y))/(length(x)-1)`
3. `((x-mean(x))'*(y-mean(y)))/sqrt(sum((x-mean(x)).^2)*sum((y-mean(y)).^2 ))`

Why in (3) we don't divide by N-2 yet the result is correct?

Comment: Who ever answers your question will do the following thing first: open the matlab help for cov, std and zscore and write down the formulas. And then just write the formula for the first two cases to proof that they equal the third case. I mean you could try it yourself and see how far you get.

Comment: My question was Why in (3) we don't divide by N-2 yet the result is correct?

Comment: As mentioned in my first answer: if you write down all formulas you will see that all possibilities are the same in the end. However, perhaps you should explain also why you expect there to be a N-2. This also drops somehow from nowhere.